# How do I add a single file back into my Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse

I have an Eclipse project.  It originally had a structure something like this:

```
MyProj
   src
      myproj
          bar.java
          baz.java
          foo.java
          [etc.]
```

Earlier, I thought I wouldn't need baz.java anymore, so I deleted it from the project, which also deleted it from disk.  Thankfully, subversion remembered the old version, because it turns out I DO need it, so now I've gotten it back into the source directory, but I can't seem to figure out how to add it back into the project.

I tried File -> Import, but that seems to only want to import directories.

I tried File -> New -> Java Class, but that creates a new, empty file.

I suppose I COULD copy my file off elsewhere, File -> New, then copy/paste it in, but I'd love to learn the ***CORRECT*** Eclipse way to add an existing file to my project.

Thanks!

[Edit: I'm on a Mac, 10.6.Latest, Eclipse Helois 20100617-1415, though I don't think it matters.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to just put them in the correct dir under your project(I think you stated SVN already replaced the file in the proper location), and hit File->refresh in Eclipse.

Edit: that wasn't working for me, I'm on a mac but I assume drag on drop should work platform independent and it was working for me.

Comment: Ah, that was easy.  (Sort of.  For some value of "easy" ;)  It turns out that I could just drag & drop the file into my src/myproj/ dir but, since the file was already there, I had to copy it to my desktop (to avoid "source & dest are same location" error), then I had to delete it in the original location (to avoid "file already exists on copy" error), then it just copied it back from desktop to src/myproj/, which is where I wanted it, anyway.  Whew!